# js string into an object with two values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort out a challenge but it is killing. I need to change a string into an object.

To be like this:

```
 { Cape Town : 9,
   George : 7,  
   Johannesburg : -1, 
   Port Elizabeth : 5
  }
```

But currently it's returning me this:

```
 {
    Cape Town 9: undefined,
    George 7: undefined,
    Johannesburg -1: undefined,
    Port Elizabeth 5: undefined
 }
```

This is my current code:

```
 var str = "Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country
 in Cape Town 9, in George 7, in Port Elizabeth 5 and in, Johannesburg -1"


var remove = str.replace("Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all    over the country:", "")
.replace(" in", "").replace("in ", "").replace("in ", "").replace(" and in",     "")

var properties = remove.split(', ');
var obj = {};
properties.forEach(function(property) {
  var tup = property.split(':');
  obj[tup[0]] = tup[1];
});

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: try to adjust and format your question content

Comment: `'and in, Johannesburg'` What's that comma doing there? Shouldn't it be `'and, in Johannesburg'` to be consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a some **extra space** in between and `:` at the end

make it

```
var str = "Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country in Cape Town 9, in George 7, in Port Elizabeth 5 and in, Johannesburg -1"
var remove = str.replace("Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country", "").replace(" in", "").replace("in ", "").replace("in ", "").replace(" and in",     "")
```

Also, you need to do the second split by space not by colon

```
var obj = {};
properties.forEach(function(property) {
  var tup = property.split(/\s\d+/);
  obj[tup[0]] = property.split(" ").pop();
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var str = "Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country in Cape Town 9, in George 7, in Port Elizabeth 5 and in, Johannesburg -1"
remove = str.replace("Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country", "").replace(" in", "").replace("in ", "").replace("in ", "").replace(" and in",     "");
var properties = remove.split(', ');
var obj = {};
properties.forEach(function(property) {
  var tup = property.split(/\s\d+/);
  obj[tup[0]] = property.split(" ").pop();
});
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( obj, 0, 4 );
```

A **shorter version** could be

```js
var str = "Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country in Cape Town 9, in George 7, in Port Elizabeth 5 and in, Johannesburg -1";
var obj = {}; 
str.split(/\s*in\s*/).forEach( function(val, index){
  if (index == 0 ) return false;
  val = val.replace(/\s*and\s*/, ""); //remove if there is 'and'
  var tup = val.split(/\s/);
  var value = tup.splice(-1);
  obj[tup.join(" ")] = value.join("").replace(",", "");
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( obj, 0, 4 );
```

Comment: gurvinder: I'd suggest improving that `replace` chain.

Comment: @Cerbrus true, replace chain can be improved. I was just showing the OP's mistakes in the attempt made by him/her.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have attached a shorter version also.

Comment: thanks guy l surely appreciate all the that you have given, do you mind if l follow all of you guys on github

Comment: @EvansMunatsa Appreciate that, but sorry to disappoint, I don't have a github account yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter solution:

```js
var str = "Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country in Cape Town 9, in George 7, in Port Elizabeth 5 and in, Johannesburg -1",
  cities = str.match(/in[\w, ]+?-?\d/g),
  output = {};

for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
  var city = cities[i].replace(/in,? /, ''),   // Remove the `in` from the current city.
      split = city.split(' '),                // Split at [space]
      temp = split.pop();                    // Get the last item from the split string, which is the temperature.
  output[split.join(' ')] = parseInt(temp); // Store the temperature for the city name.
}

console.log(output);
```

`cities` results in:
`["in Cape Town 9", "in George 7", "in Port Elizabeth 5", "in, Johannesburg -1"]`

Then the `for` loop just iterates over those and gets the city name and temperature from it, then stores it to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Split by space and pop last element:

```
var str = "Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country \
 in Cape Town 9, in George 7, in Port Elizabeth 5 and in, Johannesburg -1"


var remove = str.replace("Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country", "")
.replace(" in", "").replace("in ", "").replace("in ", "").replace(" and in",     "")

var properties = remove.split(', ');
var obj = {};
properties.forEach(function(property) {
  var tup = property.split(' ');
  var num = tup.pop();
  obj[tup.join(' ')] = num;
});

console.log(obj);
```

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f33dv8b/)

Comment: Bogdan: I'd suggest improving that `replace` chain.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.replace`, `String.split` and `String.match` functions:

```
var str = "Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country: in Cape Town 9, in George 7, in Port Elizabeth 5 and in, Johannesburg -1",
     items = str.replace("Look at this tomorrow it will be really cold all over the country:", "").split(','),
     geoObj = {};

items.forEach(function(v) {
    var parts = v.match(/\b([A-Z](\w|\W)+)([\d+-]+?)/g)[0].split(/\s+(?=[-+]?\d)/);
    geoObj[parts[0]] = parseInt(parts[1]);
});

console.log(geoObj);
```

The console.log output:

```
{
    "Cape Town": 9,
    "George": 7,
    "Port Elizabeth": 5,
    "Johannesburg": -1
}
```